# Laravel Creating Dynamic Routes to controllers from Mysql database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following table: group_pages in mysql database with page name route name :

```
   id   name      route
  --------------------
    0   About      about
    1   Contact    contact
    2   Blog       blog
```

what I am trying to do is to create dynamic routes in my : routes.php ?

Where if I go to for example: `/about` it will go to `AboutController.php` ( which will be created dynamically) is that possible? is it possible to create a dynamic controller file?

I am trying to create dynamic pages routes that links to a controller

example i want to generate this dynamically in my `routes.php`

```
Route::controller('about', 'AboutController');

Route::controller('contact', 'ContactController');

Route::controller('blog', 'BlogController');
```

Comment: but why? You have to write controller to do job anyway, so why don't You want just write routes in code, instead of increasing workload on db? What do You mean by "created dynamically" controller?

Comment: well I am trying to create dynamic pages ? where in the admin I can add these pages - name , I need to do that so I can assign permission to users to access what page they can view when they login

Comment: is there away to dynamically add those , or I have to go in my routes.php and add those controllers one by one?

Comment: But all these pages are going to be just with some content(text, images) no form and stuff?

Comment: thats whats make this hard , its a mix of text content and form etc for example if the users logged in and he goes to /about ( if he has permission ) then he could access all pages under the directory /about , like /about/index , /about/page2 etc..

Comment: so I was thinking of dynamically create a controller for each page , this way /about will have AboutController and I will go in there and add different methods for each page :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is not the right way to create dynamic pages instead, you should use a database and keep all pages in the database. For example:

```
// Create pages table for dynamic pages
id | slug | title | page_content
```

Then create `Page` `Eloquent` model:

```
class Page extends Eloquent {
    // ...
}
```

Then create  `Controller` for `CRUD`, you may use a `resource` controller or a normal controller, for example, normally a `PageController`:

```
class PageController extends BaseController {

    // Add methods to add, edit, delete and show pages

    // create method to create new pages
    // submit the form to this method
    public function create()
    {
        $inputs = Input::all();
        $page = Page::create(array(...));
    }

    // Show a page by slug
    public function show($slug = 'home')
    {
        $page = page::whereSlug($slug)->first();
        return View::make('pages.index')->with('page', $page);
    }
}
```

The `views/page/index.blade.php` view file:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
{{-- Add other parts, i.e. menu --}}
@section('content')
    {{ $page->page_content }}
@stop
```

To show pages create a route like this:

```
// could be page/{slug} or only slug
Route::get('/{slug}', array('as' => 'page.show', 'uses' => 'PageController@show'));
```

To access a page, you may require `url/link` like this:

```
http://example.com/home
http://example.com/about
```

This is a rough idea, try to implement something like this.

Comment: thanks , what is the meaning of slug , is that the directory name for example "/about"?

Comment: It's the identifier in the database, for example, `about` will be a slug to identify the about page in the database by `slug` filed.

Comment: but for the route do I need to start with 'page/{slug}'? can we do it just '{slug}'

Comment: Yes, you can just use `{page}`.

Comment: I see your point , but how this will determine inner pages for example '/about/page1' ?

Comment: how will that look in the database table ? like 1 | about/page1 | my page | some content here ? is it like that?

Comment: For this, you have to just add another field in the database and make a relationship, for example: `page_parent` and store the `id` of the page in the `page_parent` field who is a child of that page.

Comment: You may save only the `slug`, i.e. `home`, `about` etc, because you only need the `slug` to pass that to the `Page` method.

Comment: so I need two tables one for the parent and one for the childs?

Comment: No, in the same table, you may use self relationship, something described in [this article](http://heera.it/laravel-model-relationship).

Comment: I got it :) , so basically in routes.php Laravel will understand {slug} what it means? Route::get('/{slug}', array('as' => 'page.show', 'uses' => 'PageController@show'));

Comment: Yes, `{slug}` will be replaced with `home` or `about` so, `example.com/about` will hit `show` method in `PageController` and in the `$slug` the current slug will be passed.

Comment: but this is assuming all those pages are 100% dynamic static content ? I cant really edit or add my own thing , for example the blog page might have different than the about page it terms of formating

Comment: Yes you can, load the `page_content` in a form, change and update as you insert them first time. Make a gellery for image uploading, use images link once you upload it to server, just like `WordPress` as `CMS`.

Comment: You mean the page_content could be a whole html page stored in the database ?

Comment: could it be like a .blade template? so if I store the page_content to be a .blade template and then I can load that ? this way I can have more control on the .blade instead of editing that in the admin

Comment: You can replace the `page_content` using the `blade` static page template link, instead of saving the content in the database store the blade page link used to represent that page then load that page content dynamically using same method.

Comment: one more thing , how can I make certain user type access these pages for example if the user is employee he can only see /about page not the other pages how can I do that?

Comment: You need to create user `types` and map each page to types, that another big issue.

Comment: Also lets say I have a Slug page "contact" and I load contact.blade.php and it has a form : the action of the goes to the /contact POST , how could I get the post route in this case? how laravel will know where I take care of the post?

Comment: I guess I need another post route for that/

Comment: Yes, that's another issue, can i leave now if you are done :-)

Comment: can I just map it to the parent_page id ? istead of each one

Comment: Yes, it is up to you how you can tell the machine using some language to do something for you, there are so many ways, just need to tell the listener how to do it.

Comment: To save/update, you need to create another route like: `Route::post('save', array('uses' => 'PageController@save', 'as' => 'page.create'))`.

Comment: Use one method for each `route/action`.

Comment: Post another question, I'll try.

Comment: Thanks WereWolf I will post it let me see if I am on the right track

Comment: I posted one here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158564/laravel-user-permission-to-access-certain-pages

Comment: Posted an answer but rest depends on you, can't help more, sorry !

Answer (score 14):

After spending 2 hours, digging through google and Laravel source, I came up with this solution, which I think works the best and looks the cleanest. No need for redirects and multiple inner requests.

You add this route at the very bottom of routes files.
If no other routes are matched, this is executed. In the closure, you decide which controller and action to execute.
The best part is - all route parameters are passed to action, and method injection still works. The ControllerDispatcer line is from Laravel Route(r?) class.

My example would handle 2 cases - first checks if user exists by that name, then checks if an article can be found by the slug.

Laravel 5.2 (5.3 below)

```
Route::get('{slug}/{slug2?}', function ($slug) {
    $class = false;
    $action = false;

    $user = UserModel::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    if ($user) {
        $class = UserController::class;
        $action = 'userProfile';
    }

    if (!$class) {
        $article= ArticleModel::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        if ($article) {
            $class = ArticleController::class;
            $action = 'index';
        }
    }

    if ($class) {
        $route = app(\Illuminate\Routing\Route::class);
        $request = app(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class);
        $router = app(\Illuminate\Routing\Router::class);
        $container = app(\Illuminate\Container\Container::class);
        return (new ControllerDispatcher($router, $container))->dispatch($route, $request, $class, $action);
    }

    // Some fallback to 404
    throw new NotFoundHttpException;
});
```

5.3 has changed how the controller gets dispatched.

Heres my dynamic controller example for *5.3, 5.4*

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher;
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;

class DynamicRouteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * This method handles dynamic routes when route can begin with a category or a user profile name.
     * /women/t-shirts vs /user-slug/product/something
     *
     * @param $slug1
     * @param null $slug2
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($slug1, $slug2 = null)
    {
        $controller = DefaultController::class;
        $action = 'index';

        if ($slug1 == 'something') {
            $controller = SomeController::class;
            $action = 'myAction';
        }

        $container = app();
        $route = $container->make(Route::class);
        $controllerInstance = $container->make($controller);

        return (new ControllerDispatcher($container))->dispatch($route, $controllerInstance, $action);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i am looking for the same functionality. Any idea that will work on laravel 5.7 ?

Comment: it works :) any ideea how to pass arguments to 'myAction' method?

Comment: Works well, thanks - only issue is the having to re-run the same query when it lands on the second controller to get the Model again. Any way around this?

Comment: @anthonyroberts Are you talking about model bindings in the method's parameters? You'll probably need to dive into the internals of the framework, use xdebug to step through and understand if there is a way to avoid it.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);

$pages = 
Cache::remember('pages', 5, function() {
    return DB::table('pages')
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->lists('slug');

});

if(!empty($pages)) 
{
  foreach ($pages as $page)
  {
    Route::get('/{'.$page.'}', ['as' => $page, 'uses' => 'PagesController@show']);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a component available, which you can use to store routes in a database. As an extra advantage, this component only loads the current active route, so it improves performance, since not all routes are loaded into the memory.

https://github.com/douma/laravel-database-routes

Follow the installation instructions provided in the readme.

**Storing routes in the database**

The only thing needed here is injecting the `RouteManager` into for example a cli command. With `addRoute` can tell the `RouteManager` to store the route into the database. You can easily change this code and use your own repository of pages or other data to construct the routes.

```php
use Douma\Routes\Contracts\RouteManager;

class RoutesGenerateCommand extends Command 
{
    protected $signature = 'routes:generate';
    private $routeManager;

    public function __construct(RouteManager $routeManager)
    {
        $this->routeManager = $routeManager;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->routeManager->addRoute(
            new Route('/my-route', false, 'myroute', MyController::class, 'index')
        );
    }
}
```

Run this cli command every 2-5 minutes or after a change in your data to make sure the routes are recent.

**Register the RouteMiddleware in App\Http\Kernel.php**

`\Douma\Routes\Middleware\RouteMiddleware::class`

**Empty your web.php**

If you have defined any Laravel route, make sure to empty this file.

**Using routes from the database**

You can use the route in blade:

```
{{ RouteManager::routeByName('myroute')->url() }}
```

Or you can inject the `RouteManager`-interface anywhere you like to obtain the route:

```
use Douma\Routes\Contracts\RouteManager;
class MyClass
{
    public function __construct(RouteManager $routeManager) 
    {
        $this->routeManager = $routeManager;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo $this->routeManager->routeByName('myroute')->url();
    }
}
```

For more information see the readme.

Answer (score 1):

**We can make dynamic route by this way**

```
// Instanciate a router class.
$router = app()->make('router');
```

**Get Route value from Database**

```
// For route path this can come from your database.
$paths = ['path_one','path_two','path_three'];
```

**Then iterate the value to make dynamic route**

```
// Then iterate the router "get" method.
foreach($paths as $path){
    $router->resource($path, 'YourController');
}
```

**You can use GET|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE methods also**

```
// Then iterate the router "get" method.
foreach($paths as $path){
    $router->get($path, 'YourController@index')->name('yours.index');
}
```

Comment: Except this answer fails to take into account that laravel has a route cache and so you'd need to flush the cache manually everytime a route is added in the db

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. It works perfect for me

```
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Routing\Route as MainRoute;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;

Route::group([
    'prefix'     => config('app.payment.route_prefix'),
    'namespace'  => config('app.payment.route_namespace'),
    'middleware' => config('app.payment.route_middleware')
], function (Router $router) {

    /**
     * Resolve target payment method controller
     *
     * @param $key Example key [paypal]
     * @param $action
     * @return mixed
     */
    $resolver = function ($key, $action) {
        $route = app(MainRoute::class);
        $container = app(Container::class);

        // Generate App\\Http\Controllers\PaymentMethods\PaypalController
        $controller = app(sprintf('%s\\%sController', config('app.payment.route_namespace'), ucfirst($key)));

        return (new ControllerDispatcher($container))->dispatch($route, $controller, $action);
    };

    $router->post('{key}/error', function ($key) use ($resolver) {
        return $resolver($key, 'error');
    });

    $router->post('{key}/success', function ($key) use ($resolver) {
        return $resolver($key, 'success');
    });

    $router->get('{key}', function ($key) use ($resolver) {
        return $resolver($key, 'index');
    });
});
```