# Laravel User permission to access certain pages?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, user-permissions

I have created a slug pages as followed :

```
// Create pages table for dynamic pages
| id |  slug   |   title    | page_template |
|  0 | about   | about us   | about.blade   |
|  1 | contact | contact us | contact.blade |
```

I am going to access them through the following route:

```php
// could be page/{slug} or only slug inside routes.php
Route::get('/{slug}', array('as' => 'page.show', 'uses' => 'PageController@show'));
```

Where I have a PageController, so this allows me to create pages dynamically.
Referring to the solution here: [Laravel Creating Dynamic Routes to controllers from Mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145245/laravel-creating-dynamic-routes-to-controllers-from-mysql-database)

I also have a roles table:

```
// Create roles table for
| id | name  |
|  0 | user  |
|  1 | admin |
```

I also have another table for permission:

```
// permission table 
| role_id | page_id |
|    0    |    0    |
|    0    |    1    |
|    1    |    1    |
```

This will help me out with setting permission per role type, so for example if you are a user you can only access about page, and if you are admin you can access all pages etc.

My Question is: how could I make this happen, do I add a filter to my route, that checks if the user can access that slug page? So do I do this inside `routes.php` or inside `filters.php`? And how?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need a setup like following. Create classes (models) with four tables (users, roles, permissions and permission_role):

Table `roles`:

```
id | name (role name)
1  | admin
2  | user
```

Model `Role`:

```
class Role extends ELoquent {

    protected $table = 'roles';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('User', 'role_id', 'id');
    }

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Permission');
    }
}
```

Table `permissions`:

```
id | name (permission name)
1  | manage_pages (add/edit/delete)
2  | manage_users (add/edit/delete)
3  | page_about (access allowed to about page)
4  | page_contact (access allowed to contact page)
```

Model `Permission`

```
class Permission extends ELoquent {

    protected $table = 'permissions';

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
    }
}
```

Table `users`:

```
id | username | email           | password | role_id | more...
1  | admin    | admin@ymail.com | hashed   |    1    | more...
2  | user1    | user1@ymail.com | hashed   |    2    | more...
3  | user2    | user2@ymail.com | hashed   |    2    | more...
```

Model `User`

```
class User extends ELoquent {

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Role', 'role_id', 'id');
    }

    public function can($perm = null)
    {
        if(is_null($perm)) return false;
        $perms = $this->role->permissions->fetch('name');
        return in_array($perm, $perms->toArray());
    }
}
```

Table `permission_role` (pivot table):

```
id | permission_id | role_id
1  | 1             | 1
2  | 2             | 1
3  | 3             | 1
4  | 4             | 1
5  | 3             | 2
6  | 4             | 2
```

Once you have this setup then you may create filters or in your class method you may check if a logged in user has specific rule or permission then allow access to a page, otherwise doesn't allow. For example, you may check if a logged in user can access a page using something like this:

```
if(Auth::user->can('manage_pages')) {
    // Let him/her to add/edit/delete any page
}
```

Since your pages are dynamic and all pages are being shown by `show` method then in your `show` method you may check something like this:

```
public function show($slug = 'home')
{
    // assumed page slug is 'about'
    $permission = 'page_' . $slug;
    if(Auth::user->can($permission)) {
        $page = page::whereSlug('home')->get();
        return View::make('pages.index')->with('page', $page);
    }
}
```

This is really a big issue and you have to figure it out by your self. I gave you the basic idea with some implementations, now you should extend it.

---

*P/S: It's not possible to answer everything from the ground but I'm involved with another answer of this same project of your's and I suggested you to implement a permission base (ACL) so I tried to help but you need to try to implement the rest. All the best.*

Comment: Thanks Wolf , but I am confused where this table come in to play with your code permission_role ?

Comment: The `permission_role` is known as pivot table, since you have a [many- to-namy](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many) relationship between your `roles` and `permissions` table, this pivot table maps the relationship between `Role` and `Pernission`. Each `permission_id` and `role_id` in that table is a relation.

Comment: I am checking the can method you have supplied , I am wondering what does this return $perms = $this->role->permissions->fetch('name');

Comment: It'll return the permission associated with that role, try `$r = Role::with('Permission')->all(); dd($r)`, you'll get the role with all permissions associated with that role.

Comment: will this also check if the logged in user has permission to the requested page? to me this returns the name of the page and see if it exists in the permission table?

Comment: It'll check if a page is associated with that rule by checking the `page` name in the permissions array.

Comment: oh got your point , I am ganna try it like that and extend to it , but if we do it that way we don't need to add a filter to the route , because the route goes to show method and we have a check there

Comment: Yes, since your pages are dynamic so no need to add a filter.

Comment: got your point thanks I will try to implement it and see what happens

Comment: All the best and this should work because the code taken from my own project which works perfectly.

Comment: just a quick note here : for this if(Auth::user->can($permission))  this checks if the user is logged in right? and then it checks it he has access to the pages

Comment: No, it checks if the logged in user has a permission. You may handle logging in the user using [Auth](http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users) class probably in the `User` model.

Comment: so what if the user is not logged in?

Comment: You can't check for the permission if a user is not logged in and a permission is required for a logged in user only, in this case you may suggest that user to log in to view a page, so check if the user is not logged in using `Auth::check()` and if not logged in then redirect to `login` page/form.

Comment: one thing I am missing , what if the user goes to /test and test page is not a slug , how do i handle missing pages? can i add the method missingMethod to the PageController to take care of that?

Comment: You can create a handler using `App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});` in the `global.php` file. [Check this](http://laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-404-errors).

Comment: thanks this work :) , also I was wondering the PageContoller going to handle all my request even for sub pages : /admin/users/{$actions} ho can I handle that all in the PageController?

Comment: Most probably you need another method for that.

Comment: so I need to have different methods all in PageController.php this controller might get bigger :)

Comment: I am getting undefined property here : $perms = $this->role->permissions->fetch('name');

Comment: Did you implemented all the relations properly, I think you missed at any point otherwise it should work because it was from a working project of mine.

Comment: Yes everything looks exactly the same not sure why I am getting that error

Comment: ErrorException

Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$permissions

Comment: Most probably that role doesn't contain any permissions.

Comment: well I made sure it does

Comment: do you think I need a permission() method inside the user.php model

Comment: `$this->role->permissions` could be read as `$user->role->permissions` so `User` has `role()` and `Role` has `permissions()` so it should work.

Comment: ya its very strange its not really working , but when you do it that way user and role are shared by the role_id and permissions and role is also shared by the role_id , I am not sure why its not working

Comment: Make sure there is a relation between current `user` and any `role`, each user should have assigned a rile to them.

Comment: You mean this ?                                                 public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
    }

Comment: if I do this it works : Role::find(1)->permissions->toArray();

Comment: it seems that I need to specify the role_id value to give it to the permission method

Comment: Does a `User` has a role ? If not then it's the problem.

Comment: You mean the user table does it have a role_id ?

Comment: Yes, user table must contain a `role_id` and each user should have a role.

Comment: thats the mistake I didnt have role_id inside the user table , could I ask you what about making a pivot table user_role instead wouldnt that be better?

Comment: In the answer I gave, I used this approach because, one user can have only one role so there is no need to use another pivot table.

Comment: This is great,,,

we can extend this , because some applications require more specific roles like 3 different users have different access to on module etc