# How to get a slug to controller?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new in Laravel. I would like to ask, how can I find a slug in controller? 
For example, my actually url is www.example.com/contact-us

I need to get a "contact-us" value in a variable in controller. Is there any simple way?

On another url, for example www.example.com/faq I need to have the value "faq" in the same variable. How can I do it? Thank you a lot

Using laravel 5.5

This is, what is in my routes file:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/podmienky-pouzitia', 'StaticController@index');
Route::get('/faq', 'StaticController@index');
Route::get('/o-projekte', 'StaticController@index');
```

This is, what is in my StaticController file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\StaticModel;

class StaticController extends Controller
{
    public function index($slug) {
        var_dump($slug); // I need to get a variable with value of my actual slug
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't this "slug" be an action of your controller?

Comment: The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing) has a lot of detail about routing. What have you tried?

Comment: No. I would like to create something like "staticPage" controller, which would only print the content. Nothing else. I don't want to create a controller for each static subpage :O So I would like to take a slug and by slug find the row in DB, so I can print the text down. I have for about 12-13 static subpages, so I think, it would be very stupid to create 12 controllers, which will do the same thing. So all I need is the name of variable, where my slug will be saved and I can use it inside Controller. Of course, if exists...

Comment: You do know your [routes can have parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#required-parameters) right? You can have a route `/staticpages/{slug}` (or something) and have it handled by a single controller action which accepts the `$slug` as a parameter

Comment: I dont want to have word "staticpages" inside URL. Because of "seo"... are you sure there is no variable with value I actually need? Sorry, I'm beginner.

Comment: You don't have to have word "staticpages" inside url. He just gave you an example. You can have there whaterver you want, or just `/{slug}`

Comment: Ok. If I write something like this: public function index($slug) {
        var_dump($slug);
    } I receive an error: "Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\StaticController::index()". It means, there is no value in $slug :(

Comment: Without the configuration file, it is hard to say why it isn't working and how to fix it

Comment: What is configuration file? I will try to post my codes below.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please, see the codes there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the static page slug a parameter:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/{slug}', 'StaticController@index'); //This replaces all the individual routes
```

In Static controller:

```
 public class StaticController extends Controller {
     public function index($slug) {
          // if the page was /faq then $slug = "faq"              
     }
 }
```

However be wary that the order you declare the routes matters. Therefore you must declare all other routes before the general "catch-all" route at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `action()` helper function to get the URL that points to a given Controller & Method.

routes.php:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

HomeController.php:

```
class HomeController extends Controller {
    public function index (Request $request) {
        $url = action('HomeController@index');
        // $url === 'http://www.example.com/home'

        // OR

        $path = $request->path();
        // $path === 'home';
    }
}
```

If you use the first way, you can then use the `request()` helper (or the `Request` instance) to remove the domain from the string:

```
$url = str_replace(request()->root(), '', $url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring several routes for each page/slug, you should just declare one route with a route parameter, so for example:

```
Route::get('/{slug}', 'StaticController@index');
```

In this case, the `index` method will receive the `slug` in `$slug` parameter, for example:

```
public function index($slug)
{
    var_dump($slug);
}
```

So now, you can make requests using something like the following:

```
http://example.com/faq // for faq page
http://example.com/contact-us // for contact page
```

So, the `$slug` will now contain the `faq/contact-us` and so on. But, in this case, you'll have problem, for example, `http://exampe.com/home` will also similar to the dynamic route with slug so, if you declare the `home` route before the dynamic route (one with `{slug}`) then the `StaticController@index` will be invoked so either, you declare the dynamic route with slug under a parent namespace, for example:

```
Route::get('/static/{slug}', 'StaticController@index');
```

So, you can easily differentiate the routes or declare the dynamic route with slug parameter and add a where constraint in your route declaration if you have some predefined static pages with those slugs. [Here is a somewhat similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145245/laravel-creating-dynamic-routes-to-controllers-from-mysql-database/23145539#23145539), could be helpful. Also, check more about [route constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints).

Update: You can also add a route constraint using something like the following:

```
Route::get('/{slug}', 'StaticController@index')->where('slug', 'faq|contact|something');
```

The above declaration will only match the following urls:

```
http://example.com/faq
http://example.com/contact
http://example.com/something
```